# plot_ly with transforms and color mapping

Tags: r, r-plotly

I've been trying to use `plot_ly` with `transforms` (ultimately to subset data from a dropdown menu) *and* a color mapping.

Following is a reproducible example based on `mtcars`:

### `transforms` without color mapping

If I *exclude* the color mapping, everything works as expected:

```
library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)

plot_ly(
    data = mtcars %>% rownames_to_column("id"),
    x = ~mpg, y = ~disp, text = ~id,
    type = "scatter", mode = "markers+text",
    marker = list(size = 10, opacity = 0.8),
    transforms = list(
        list(
            type = "filter",
            target = ~cyl,
            operation = "=",
            value = sort(unique(mtcars$cyl))[1])))
```

[image]

Data is filtered for `mtcars$cyl` values matching `sort(unique(mtcars$cyl))[1] = 4`. So far so good.

### `transforms` with color mapping

I now like to color-code markers based on the number of carburetors from `mtcars$carb`; if I add a color mapping, I end up with

```
library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)

plot_ly(
    data = mtcars %>% rownames_to_column("id"),
    x = ~mpg, y = ~disp, text = ~id, color = ~as.factor(carb),
    type = "scatter", mode = "markers+text",
    marker = list(size = 10, opacity = 0.8),
    transforms = list(
        list(
            type = "filter",
            target = ~cyl,
            operation = "=",
            value = sort(unique(mtcars$cyl))[1])))
```

[image]

Somehow, the `transforms` filter is ignored, as the plot shows entries from `mtcars` where `cyl != 4`. I actually don't understand which element `plot_ly` decides to show here.

Would somebody be able to provide any insight? Many thanks.

Comment: Hi @FKneip; not an answer but I can confirm the issue with some random sample data; this also happens when you add a `symbol` mapping. I have opened an [issue on the GitHub's project site](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1502).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't seem to like the `factor` in the `color` in combination with the `filter`. It looks like stuff is getting shuffled and screwed up, e.g. `color = ~factor(carb, levels = unique(carb))` will give you yet another selection and plot.

Below is working with a `factor` (including the `color` in the `marker`). Specifying just `color = ~carb` would work as well. I understand none of these really give you the same plot / legend though.

```
library(plotly)
library(magrittr)

plot_ly(
  data = mtcars %>% tibble::rownames_to_column("id"),
  x = ~mpg, y = ~disp, text = ~id,
  type = "scatter", mode = "markers+text",
  marker = list(color = ~as.factor(carb), size = 10, opacity = 0.8),
  transforms = list(
    list(
      type = "filter",
      target = ~cyl,
      operation = "=",
      value = sort(unique(mtcars$cyl))[1])))
```

---

**Edit**

You can apparently work around the re-shuffling problem by **sorting your data first according to the factor you desire to use**. The code below works fine in this respect, although I still don't like having all the levels in the legend. Hope it's of some help nonetheless:

```
library(plotly)
library(magrittr)

xx <- mtcars[order(mtcars$carb), ]

plot_ly(
  data = xx %>% tibble::rownames_to_column("id"),
  x = ~mpg, y = ~disp, text = ~id, color = ~factor(carb),
  type = "scatter", mode = "markers+text",
  marker = list(size = 10, opacity = 0.8),
  transforms = list(
    list(
      type = "filter",
      target = ~xx$cyl,
      operation = "=",
      value = sort(unique(xx$cyl))[1])))
```

**Explanation**

Looking at `plotly:::plotly_build.plotly`, we can see that sorting is applied in certain cases, e.g. when working with **groups**, or **discrete colors or symbols**. This sorting however does not include the `transforms/filter`, therefore the two things get out of sync.

If you want to look this up, you can also find `arrange_safe()` within https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/blob/master/R/plotly_build.R.

It should obviously be considered a **bug**, but a good fix is maybe not exactly trivial.

Another way of confirming that else it's fine, is if you just mask `arrange_safe`. E.g. like below:

```
library(godmode)
arrange_safe_new <- function(x, y) x
godmode:::assignAnywhere("arrange_safe", arrange_safe_new)
```

Afterwards, your case will be fine (but of course you might need the original `arrange_safe` functionality for other cases, so this is really just to prove a point).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. (1) Your edit seems to do what I'm after but I have to say that I don't understand why sorting my data first would affect the color mapping/filtering. Do you have an explanation why this works? (2) Your first answer also does the correct filtering but doesn't produce a legend. I didn't even know you could specify the color mapping inside `marker`. In [#121 Manage colors with plotly](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/121-manage-colors-with-plotly/) the color mapping is added directly in `plot_ly`. Do you know what is the "correct" way?

Comment: As for 1), I believe there is a bug, which is avoided by sorting up front. I might have time to check this in more detail tomorrow. Regarding 2), I haven’t done any reading on when to use what approach. My naive intuition would be to specify it „directly“ whenever that‘s sufficient to produce what you want, and switch to the more low-level specification when necessary

Comment: @FKneip I added some detail explanation to the answer now

Comment: `godmode:::assignAnywhere` looks fun.  But the traditional `assignInNamespace` is almost certainly safer.

Comment: Thanks @RolandASc and @dww for the extended details. To be honest this seems to seriously exceed my basic R knowledge, because I've got no idea what `godmode:::assignAnywhere` does. Do you think it's worth adding this to the GitHub bug issue mentioned in the first comment to my post?

Comment: Maybe you could just add a comment (to the GitHub issue) saying that sorting isn't applied consistently in `plotly_build` and add the link to this question here?

Comment: RolandASc and @FKneip: I've added a comment to the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1502#issuecomment-478201766) with a ping to both of you (not sure if you're on GitHub FKneip?).